# Blackberry MapView plot coords

Tags: blackberry, android-mapview

I was wondering if it is possible to plot locations/coords on the MapView class of blackberry.
http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/5.0.0api/net/rim/blackberry/api/maps/MapView.html

In iOS I made an app the drops pins(annotations) on the MKMapView but I can't find something simular for blackberry?

Any guidance will be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have basically two options:

1) If you want the map to be embedded within your own application, use the [`MapField`](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/5.0.0api/net/rim/device/api/lbs/MapField.html) to add a map to your screen and then override the `paint()` method to manually draw your pins on the screen.

2) If you just want to launch the maps app and let it handle everything, then use the [`MapsArguments`](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/5.0.0api/net/rim/blackberry/api/invoke/MapsArguments.html) to pass info to the app via an [`Invoke.invokeApplication()`](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/5.0.0api/net/rim/blackberry/api/invoke/Invoke.html).

Answer (score 1):

On BlackBerry7 you can do it with MapMarker, without having to override paint(). Also, you can use GoogleMapField, see code here: https://github.com/rhomobile/rhodes/blob/master/platform/bb/rhodes/src/rhomobile/mapview/GoogleMapField.java

Comment: Yeah but most users in South Africa use the Curve 8520 and it only has OS 5.0 on it

Comment: Then you can use the other solution I offered: GoogleMapField