# Blackberry app map clickable marker

Tags: blackberry, dictionary, click, marker

I am thinking about developing a BB app that is based on maps provided by BB.
The trick is that I need the markers on the map to be clickable.
I did a little research and a lot of people are saying that this is not possible.
Has anyone done it so he can point me to the right direction?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

http://www.wikitude.com -> this application does.

You can extend the MapField class, and then handle the interaction with your markers internally in your class (paint() and touchEvent() should be overridden).

Or eventually, as with many UI-classes, you can do "impossible" things just by painting them on a Bitmap, and manipulating it before rendering on screen.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your fast reply. I saw the app you are talking about and I noticed that it requires OS 7. Is the process you are talking about available for OS 6?

Comment: yep, OS 7 has built-in support for clickable markers; see an alternative open source solution here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6939882/blackberry-mapview-plot-coords/7207092#7207092

Comment: Yes but this seems to work with Google Maps API. Isn't there something similar for BB Maps in OS 6?

Comment: Yes, this also works on OS 6, the BB OS 6 version of the application has not been released yet, but it works the same way.